# Haar integral of rational function of unitaries

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration, random-matrices, haar-measure

I'm trying to compute the following Haar integral over the unitary group:
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{U}(d)}\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k,l=1}^d u_{ik}\overline{u_{il}}c_{kl}}dU.
$$ Is there anything known about the value of such integrals? I haven't been able to find anything that studies the integrals of either non polynomial functions or non class functions of unitaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There exist no closed-form expressions for arbitrary $d$ for the integral over the unitary group $\mathbb{U}(d)$ of a rational function of the matrix elements.
There are asymptotic results for large $d$, see for example [J. Math. Phys. 37, 4904 (1996)](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9604059). The leading order term for $\text{tr}\,C$ of order $d$ is
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{U}(d)}\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k,l}u_{ik}\overline{u_{il}}c_{kl}}dU=\frac{d}{\text{tr}\,C}+{\cal O}(1/d),$$
independent of the index $i$.

Alternatively, if $d$ is not large but the matric $C$ is close to the unit matrix, $c_{kl}=\delta_{kl}+\epsilon_{kl}$, one can expand
$$
\begin{split}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{U}(d)}\dfrac{1}{\sum_{k,l}u_{ik}\overline{u_{il}}c_{kl}}dU & =1-\int\limits_{\mathbb{U}(d)}\sum_{k,l}u_{ik}\overline{u_{il}}\epsilon_{kl}\,dU+{\cal O}(\epsilon^2)\\
 & =1-\frac{1}{d}\sum_{k}\epsilon_{kk}+{\cal O}(\epsilon^2).
\end{split}$$

Comment: This is what I feared. Thank you. However, the first estimate you gave will probably be useful since the specific $C$ I need will have trace d.